# Django Model: Default method for field called multiple times

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following two models (just for a test):

```
class IdGeneratorModel(models.Model):

    table = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True,
                             null=False, max_length=32)
    last_created_id = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=False,
                                             unique=False)

    @staticmethod
    def get_id_for_table(table: str) -> int:
        try:
            last_id_set = IdGeneratorModel.objects.get(table=table)
            new_id = last_id_set.last_created_id + 1
            last_id_set.last_created_id = new_id
            last_id_set.save()
            return new_id
        except IdGeneratorModel.DoesNotExist:
            np = IdGeneratorModel()
            np.table = table
            np.save()
            return IdGeneratorModel.get_id_for_table(table)

class TestDataModel(models.Model):

    class Generator:
        @staticmethod
        def get_id():
            return IdGeneratorModel.get_id_for_table('TestDataModel')

    id = models.BigIntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True,
                                editable=False, auto_created=True,
                                default=Generator.get_id)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

Now I use the normal Django Admin site to create a new Test Data Set element. What I expected (and maybe I'm wrong here) is, that the method `Generator.get_id()` is called exactly one time when saving the new dataset to the database. But what really happens is, that the `Generator.get_id()` method is called three times:

- First time when I click the "add a Test Data Set" button in the admin area
- A second time shortly after that (no extra interaction from the user's side)
- And a third time when finally saving the new data set

The first time could be OK: This would be the value pre-filled in a form field. Since the primary key field is not displayed in my form, this may be an unnecessary call.

The third time is also clear: It's done before saving. When it's *really* needed.

The code above is only an example and it is a test for me. In the real project I have to ask a remote system for an ID instead from another table model. But whenever I query that system, the delivered ID gets locked there - like the `get_id_for_table()` method counts up.

I'm sure there are better ways to get an ID from a method *only when really needed* - the method should be called exactly one time - when inserting the new dataset. Any idea how to achieve that?

Forgot the version: It's Django 1.8.5 on Python 3.4.

Comment: Thats not atomic (`save()`), youre going to be in a world of hurt when you realize in down the line that your ids are duplicated. Whats wrong with the DB doing auto number again?

Comment: This is just an example for a test. In the real project, I get the IDs from a remote service. This service takes of course care about delivering each ID only a single time. But I need to make sure that the method that calls the service is just calleed exactly once for a single new dataset.

Comment: I have ran into issues in the past that `signals` call my code twice, and its a bit of a pain to debug, but not to worry. PDB to the rescue, or `ipdb` better. `pip install ipdb` then inside your `get_id_for_table()` add `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` then look at your console and wait for the break, type `where` and you'll see how and why it was called.

Comment: Are you a Java programmer by any chance? This really isn't how you write Python.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an answer to your question, but could be a solution to your problem*

I believe this issue is very complicated. Especially because you want a transaction that spans a webservice call and a database insert... What I would use in this case: generate a uuid locally. This value is practially guaranteed to be unique in the 4d world (time + location) and use that as id. Later, when the save is done, sync with your remote services.

Comment: In fact, this is currently part of my plan B.